Movie with a man with a Chinese queue hairstyle riding a bike with a child in front and a woman in the back, all smiling
I've seen this picture on several websites. It shows three people who seem to be from a movie: a man (the cyclist), a child seated in front, and a woman at the back. They're all smiling as they ride the bike, and the man has a traditional Chinese queue hairstyle.
Can anyone identify the film this image is from?


2009 Hong Kong film, Bodyguards and Assassins, starring Donnie Yen and Fan Bingbing, directed by Chen Kexin.
Also known as October Siege (十月圍城).
bts:

https://slide.ent.sina.com.cn/slide_4_163_2468.html#p=1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodyguards_and_Assassins
From what I recall, the image went around on social media for a while, but when you actually watch the movie, that scene is either extremely short or is not in there at all. The movie is an action film, and the cycle ride, IIRC  was a spontaneous unscripted shot (in a scene where there are very short flashbacks to memories).
The cycle ride was shot because the two actors (Yen, Bingbing) had just shot a scene in the market, with Yen's character spotting his ex-wife, and she (Bingbing) confronting him; and afterwards the two brought up a memory from a much older and locally very popular film, made by the same director, in which the two characters in that film are seen cycling through the streets. Inspired, the director shot this cycle ride with their on-screen daughter and posted photos of it to social media. It would appear that this scene never made it to the final film.
It appears that the behind the scenes, unit still, or still photography, was used for the social media photo rather than an actual frame from the movie.

Chen Kexin: ... it's memories "There was no scene in the script, and Fan Bingbing's clothes were borrowed from extras."


Chen Kexin said that he was filming a scene where Fan Bingbing and Donnie Yen met by chance in the vegetable market that day, and after the filming ended, the two hummed "Sweet Honey" together, so Chen Kexin suddenly had a flash of inspiration and added this scene. Chen Kexin said, "In fact, this scene is a scene in the movie where Donnie Yen reminisces about the past, and riding a bicycle to Fan Bingbing is just a small fragment of many past events, and it is these fragments that give him the courage to change from a gambler to a real man."


Donnie Yen recalled, "I filmed 4 scenes that day, two literary scenes during the day, one was a bitter reunion with Bingbing in the crowd, and the other was a sweet memory of riding a bicycle; There were two martial arts scenes in the evening, one of the crying scenes was very bitter, and the last one was a hot fighting scene. In one day, Peter and Teddy seemed to have made me a feast and tasted the ups and downs of life. ”

Reference: cycle scene in 1996's "Sweet Honey" (甜蜜蜜) starring Maggie Cheung and Leon Lai, also directed by Chen Kexin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comrades:_Almost_a_Love_Story)

link:



